# httpClient connection not closing

Tags: java, http, connection, vert.x

Version

```
vert.x core: 3.3.0
```

Context

Am just trying to run http client in core examples io.vertx.example.core.http.simple.Client.
While running this example its found that the established connection not closing after completion of request.

Server side I didnt see any issue. Since while trying with jmeter and server its working fine. So I think that the problem is in the HttpClient.

Anyone can help me on this?

Thanks in advance.
Steps to reproduce

```
running io.vertx.example.core.http.simple.Server code
running io.vertx.example.core.http.simple.Client code
```

Extra

The following shown even after the request and response is ended. while giving 
LINUX

```
lsof -i -P
java 32551 USER 223u IPv4 16264097 0t0 TCP localhost:8080->localhost:26980 (ESTABLISHED)
java 32634 USER 218u IPv4 16264087 0t0 TCP localhost:26980->localhost:8080 (ESTABLISHED)
```

WINDOWS

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         FSSCHND12957:56893     ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:56893        FSSCHND12957:8080      ESTABLISHED
```

Tried in both LINUX and WINDOWS system.

Client Code

```
package io.vertx.example.core.http.simple;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.example.util.Runner;

/*

    @author Tim Fox
    */
    public class Client extends AbstractVerticle {

    // Convenience method so you can run it in your IDE
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runner.runExample(Client.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
    vertx.createHttpClient().getNow(8080, "localhost", "/", resp -> {
    System.out.println("Got response " + resp.statusCode());
    resp.bodyHandler(body -> {
    System.out.println("Got data " + body.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
    });
    });
    }
    }
```

Server Code

```
package io.vertx.example.core.http.simple;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.example.util.Runner;

/*

    @author Tim Fox
    */
    public class Server extends AbstractVerticle {

    // Convenience method so you can run it in your IDE
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runner.runExample(Server.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> {
    req.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("
    Hello from vert.x!
    ");

    }).listen(8080);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to close the httpClient which we normally do in java. Only end() is not closing the connection. httpClient.close() is required.... This solved my issue..

Modified code:

```
public class Client extends AbstractVerticle {

// Convenience method so you can run it in your IDE
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runner.runExample(Client.class);
}

@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    HttpClient httpClient = vertx.createHttpClient().getNow(8080, "localhost", "/", resp -> {
        System.out.println("Got response " + resp.statusCode());
        resp.bodyHandler(body -> {
            System.out.println("Got data " + body.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
            httpClient.close();
        });
    });
}
}
```